# Node.js - Get a single XML value

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I am simply trying to output a single value (thumbnail) of an XML file in Node.js.  I feel like I am *so close* but can't figure it out.

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/game/1', (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) { return console.log(error); }
    console.log(body.thumbnail);
});
```

Comment: You might want to start by looking to see what `body` is. I wouldn't expect it to be an object with a `thumbnail` property.

Comment: I was getting the XML object back correctly in body. I just can't figure out how to grab a single value (thumbnail) out of the XML object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a XML parser, for example [`xml2js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) :

```
var request = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

request('https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/game/1', (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) { return console.log(error); }
    parseString(body, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: That would make sense.  Now I get a couple of arrays.  Still need to figure out how to get the single XML node value.

Comment: What do you call "the single XML value" ?

Comment: For example, there is a node in the XML file called "yearpublished" with a value of "1986".  Here is what the top of the XML structure looks like:

<boardgames>
    <boardgame objectid="1">
        <yearpublished>1986</yearpublished>

Comment: Here is the furthest I have gotten: console.dir( result.boardgames.boardgame );  The following returns 'undefined': console.dir( result.boardgames.boardgame.yearpublished );

Comment: Looks like i'm not the only one with this problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238493/xml2js-how-is-the-output

Comment: Because `result.boardgames.boardgame` is an array, so if you want to retrieve "yearpublished", do the following : `result.boardgames.boardgame[0].yearpublished`

Answer (score 0):

Double check by using the console to see all of body I.e:

```
      console.log(body)
```

Then you will see the options you have available. Show us what you get and we could be more specific or it may be enough for you to work out at a glance. You are on the right track. It just depends on the data structure that is there for you.

Comment: Yes, I was already getting the XML object back correctly in body.  I just can't figure out how to grab a single value out of the XML object.