# XML2JS remove square brackets surrounding values

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml2js

i'm using the xml2js node package to parse an xml feed.  Is there any way to prevent the values being surrounded by square brackets?

E.g. 
"reference": ["ABC123"]
should be
"reference": "ABC123"

```
"items": [
    {
        "reference": ["ABC123"],
        "hours": ["35"]
    },
    {
        "reference": ["XYZ123"],
        "hours": ["20"]
    }
]
```

Comment: what is the input xml and what is the code you used to convert it

Comment: Hi, the XML looks like this (I have no control over it).
<reference>
<![CDATA[ ABC123]]>
</reference>
<hours>
<![CDATA[ 35 ]]>
</hours>

Comment: what is the code you used to convert? an executable sample from stackblitz is easy to help you

Comment: The code to convert it 
xml2js.parseString(theXML, function (err, result) { //Do stuff here });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238493/xml2js-how-is-the-output

Comment: var parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray : false}); it seems'

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj thanks for your help, that works perfect.  I ended up adding that parameter directly on require(): 
var xml2js = require('xml2js').Parser({explicitArray : false});

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js').Parser({explicitArray : false});
```

results in

```
"items": [
    {
        "reference": "ABC123",
        "hours": "35"
    },
    {
        "reference": "XYZ123",
        "hours": "20"
    }
]
```